# propagate custom baggages to downstream services

Tags: open-telemetry, otel, open-telemetry-java

Our app is spring boot based. Earlier we were using Spring cloud slueth for trace and baggage propogation.
Recently we started used Splunk OTEL instrumentation agent (java) and removed slueth library. Traces are getting propagated properly.
but could not find any option to propagate custom baggages to downstream services.

Example, Caller of my app passes "X-REQUEST-ID" in headers in API call. I want to pass the same header to other downstream services my app is calling. I believe X-REQUEST-ID is considered as custom baggage so looking for your help on how to configure that in splunk otel agent library.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.